# let statement application consequences

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, ecmascript-6

I [found](http://www.toptal.com/nodejs/interview-questions) such an explanation why cycles with variable declared with var in node is faster than in chrome:

> Within a web browser such as Chrome, declaring the variable i outside
>   of any function’s scope makes it global and therefore binds it as a
>   property of the window object. As a result, running this code in a web
>   browser requires repeatedly resolving the property i within the
>   heavily populated window namespace in each iteration of the for loop.
>
> In Node.js, however, declaring any variable outside of any function’s
>   scope binds it only to the module’s own scope (not the window object)
>   which therefore makes it much easier and faster to resolve.

Curious about a `let` statement in Ecmascript6: does it make calculations faster using more block scope declared variables in loops or it is just a safety measure against name collisions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The goal with `let` was to have better scoping mechanism in JavaScript (no more wrapping things in anonymous functions just for the sake of scoping). Any performance gains are just cherry on the top.